# Implementing a scheduler on android

Tags: android

Hi I am a novice on Android Development who has started reading Android development tutorials.  I would like to develop or create a scheduling app of my own.

Can someone point me to specific/general APIs or reading material which i can follow. Thanks!

Comment: "scheduling app?" What do you exactly mean by that? Care to explain more?

Comment: Well a sort of a timetable which would organise my activities on a calendar and inform me of any conflicts and suggestions where i could place them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked out [Calendar Provider](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html)?

*The Calendar Provider API allows you to perform query, insert, update, and delete operations on calendars, events, attendees, reminders, and so on. The Calender Provider API can be used by applications and sync adapters.*